# How can I forward HttpResponse to an open client socket? (Java Program acts as a proxy)

Tags: java, apache, sockets, proxy, httpresponse

I am using httpclient lib from apache. I managed to get an HttpResponse by sending a GET request to the server. Now what I am trying to do is to send that response that I got to a clientSocket output stream.

So basically I want to send whatever I received from the server to the open client connection. Since I am using HttpClient I get the response in the form of an HttpResponse object. I tried the following:

```
private void forwardRequest(String header, String url){

    try {

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    CloseableHttpResponse response;

    //Adding the request headers to httpget
    String lines[] = header.split("\\n");

    for (String str : lines) {

        String parts[] = str.split(":", 2);
        httpget.addHeader(parts[0], parts[1]);

    }

    HttpResponse respone;

    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    //It works till here I can read from the response and print out the html page
    //But after this I don't know how to send it to client
    OutputStream bos = clientSocket.getOutputStream(); 
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bos); 
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

     while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            pw.println(line);

            //bos.write(line.getBytes());        //This also doesn't work
     }

     response.close();
}
```

Also clientSocket is a global variable which is associcated with a ServerSocket like:

`clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();`

I don't expect a full solution. Just point me in the right direction.. Thanks a ton!

**EDIT:**

I tried the following based on what EJP suggested.. It's still not working. I was wondering if it was correctly implemented?

```
int portNumber = 8012; // port on which the program listens

        ServerSocket serverSocket =
                new ServerSocket(portNumber); //the socket at which the program listens 
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();  //clientSocket of the program
        Socket toServer = new Socket("localhost", 8089); //proxy server to which program connects
        PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(toServer.getOutputStream(), true);
        PrintWriter outClient =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader inServer = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(toServer.getInputStream()));

            ) {
        String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(inputLine); //Writing to proxy server
                outClient.println(inServer.readLine()); //writing back to original request sender
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The client made an HTTP request, so it will be expecting an HTTP response. If the global clientSocket is just a raw TCP socket and not an HttpClient, then you need to add the HTTP response protocol header yourself.

You have the content from the server, you'll want to first return an HTTP response 200 OK, then empty line with carriage return + linefeed (CR+LF), then Content-length: , then the document. If you are just proxying text documents, then you could convert to a string here, but otherwise, I would just pass the mime type, charset, and entity through as the raw bytes as the web server responded, that way you can proxy any document, including images or binary files.

It will look something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: length

<html> ...
</html>
```

To pass the http headers through from the server:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
// technically you should check the HTTP response rather than assume it is a 200
int statusCode = httpResp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if(statusCode != 200)
    ... // do something with non 200 responses ?

clientSocket.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");

Header[] responseHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();
for(Header header : responseHeaders) {
     clientSocket.write(header.toString() + "\r\n");
}

clientSocket.write("\r\n"); // empty line required

// Use BufferedInputStream to deal in bytes
BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(entity.getContent());
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf, 8192)) > 0) {
   clientSocket.write(buf, bytesRead);
}
```

I say "something like this", don't take this literal, I doubt it compiles. I don't have dev station in front of me, but this is the general idea.

NOTE: Since you are using the Apache client lib, you should be able to use the specific HTTP client instead of writing the raw protocol. This will abstract the HTTP protocol away somewhat. I'll update the answer later if nobody else provides a better one.

Comment: I also though of that and I dumped all the headers that I got from response.getAllHeaders() to the output stream but it still didn't work. I am thinking there is something wrong with how I am writing to the clientSocket. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you starting your response with "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" ?

Comment: I tweaked answer to support byte mode read, plus my original was plain wrong in that it was treating entity.getContent() as a byte array, which it is not, it is an InputStream, so I wrapped it in a BufferedInputStream.

Comment: OK I implemented some of your code like the header part is right..But you cant directly write to clientSocket. You need to call the outputstream and then write to it and even then you can't write a string. You have to write bytes. Finally I think I need to modify the while loop condition also..shouldn't it be something like int n != -1 where n is the no of bytes read? I need to do some more research..

Answer (score 0):

If you're just forwarding requests and responses you don't have any need to engage in the HTTP protocol at all beyond the first line of the request. If the client knows you're the proxy you will get either a `GET` request with the full URL or else a `CONNECT` request ditto. All you have to do is connect to the target and then just copy bytes in both directions simultaneously.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and copied it from one input stream to another but still no joy! I still think yours is the correct way forward.. I edited my answer to reflect your suggestions. Is it done the right way?